# Embedded questions

Tags: questions

I have been knowing that word order remains unchanged for a subjective question. For instance:

> "Who are you?"

The above is an interrogative sentence. According to the rule the embedded question should  be -

> "I don't know who are you "

But, I found on internet that "I don't know who you are "  is being used more.

Which one is correct?

1) I don't know who you are . 
2) I don't know who are you.

,

Comment: *I don't know who you are* is a ***statement***, not a question.

Comment: Where did you get that rule? As far as I know, an embedded question does **not** invert the subject and the verb, unlike a direct question.

Answer (score 3):

"I don't know who you are" is a declarative sentence making a statement about my knowledge. It can imply a question, but is not actually a question.

"I don't know; who are you?" is a compound sentence that would be a response to a question and a question in return. You need the punctuation to be be grammatically correct.